# Does forEach { } automatically close a stream?

Tags: kotlin

I know that `Files.newDirectoryStream(directory).use { ... }` will automatically close the stream once the function in the curly brackets is completed.

Will the stream also be closed if I use `.forEach { ... }` instead of `.use { ... }`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more a Java question than a Kotlin question as this concerns a method defined in the Java API. Kotlin allows you to use `forEach` here because `DirectoryStream` is an `Iterable`, which defines the `forEach`, but this does not close this stream.

As documented on [`DirectoryStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html):

> A `DirectoryStream` is opened upon creation and is closed by invoking
> the close method. Closing a directory stream releases any resources
> associated with the stream. Failure to close the stream may result in
> a resource leak. The try-with-resources statement provides a useful
> construct to ensure that the stream is closed [...]

In other words, when you use a directory stream, you're responsible for closing it. That means that in Java, you need to use try-with-resources (or explicitly call close), in Kotlin this means you should use `use`:

```kotlin
Files.newDirectoryStream(directory).use { 
    it.forEach { ... }
}
```